# It there a way to get a matrix of maximum values in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matrix

The problem is that I have an image which contains RGB channels. 
I want to get from it a matrix with the maximum values for image across the axis - which is channels.

for example

```
np.random.seed(42)
rand=np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(4,8,3), dtype="uint8")
rand[0][np.newaxis,:,:]=
  [[[102, 220, 225],
    [ 95, 179,  61],
    [234, 203,  92],
    [  3,  98, 243],
    [ 14, 149, 245],
    [ 46, 106, 244],
    [ 99, 187,  71],
    [212, 153, 199]]
```

From this I want to get a matrix which will look like this [[220],[179],[234],[243],[245],[244],[187],[212]].

Argmax gives me an index of such values.

```
 np.argmax(exp,2) #array([[2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

How to use this info to get the values themself or are there any other methods to get them?

The same question is for the full matrix, not only for one row.

Comment: To directly get those max values, use `rand.max(axis=-1)`?

Comment: @Divakar, yes, that is an answer, thank you. For some reason found only amax and argmax functions...

Comment: So, what did you try with `amax`?

Comment: Probably, I have forgotten to use axis :) 
It gave me only the maximum number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found an answer - it is as simple as np.max(rand,axis=2) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53045439/8668595).

And as in @Divakar comment - another way it to use rand.max(axis=-1).